# Old LG screen/tv no signal on HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, amd-graphics

When I run `xrandr` when the screen is off I can see the HDMI port "connected" with all the screen resolutions options fine.

However, when I turn the screen on, I just get a blank screen and when i run `xrandr` again the HDMI port shows as "disconnected" and I can't see any resolution or what so ever.

My video card is AMD 480 and trying to run Ubuntu 20.04 but have been having this issue with older versions of Ubuntu, actually its one of the main reasons I didnt switch to Ubuntu yet.

Note that my screen is working fine on Windows 10.

Edited:

LG Model as Requested: LG DM2780A

Comment: I had an old TV that had to be turned on before I booted the PC to get it to work.

Comment: i tried that, i tried to turn it on and off and i tried to unplug/plug the HDMI cable while running Ubuntu... nothing seem to do it :(

Comment: Third LG monitor problem I've heard of. Providing a model could've helped. I had a problem with Flatron E2042 https://askubuntu.com/q/749358

Comment: The same happens to my LG M2280A-PM. Another thing that happens is, when computer boots up with HDMI connected, I log in and use Fn-F8 to switch to 'External only' display then the monitor enters 'No Signal' mode. I have to unplug and re-plug again for it to work. I'm trying to find the cause. I'll report my findings here.